# Small prime not dividing any among a "sparse" set of numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}_{\le n^2}$ be such that $\forall_{a,b\in S, a\neq b} |a-b|\ge n$. Is there always a $p=O(n)$ dividing only $O(1)$ of numbers from $S$?

Comment: Let's see if I understand: do you want to know if given any set-valued sequence $S_{\bullet}$ such that $S_{n}\subseteq\Bbb N_{\le n^2}$ and $\inf\limits_{a,b\in S_n, a\ne b} \lvert a-b\rvert\ge n$, there is a sequence $p_\bullet:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $p_n= O(n)$ and $\lvert S_n\cap p_n\Bbb Z\rvert=O(1)$?

Comment: @Gae.S. Looks right to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as it turns out. There are $O(n/\log n)$ such primes. Divide $\{1,\dots,n^2\}$ into $O(n/\log n)$ intervals of size $O(n\log n)$. For each such interval, choose one of the primes that is $O(n)$, and pick $\gg \log n$ multiples of that prime from the interval with minimal separation exceeding $n$. (Hopefully this outline is enough for you to work out the details.)

Comment: I guess I should've thought more about it, thanks!